# Classifying maps and transition functions

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, fiber-bundles, principal-bundles, classifying-spaces

Suppose a space $X'$ is obtained from $X$ by attaching an $i$-cell, i.e., $$X' = X \cup_\phi e^i$$ where $\phi: \partial e^i \to X$ is the attaching map.  Let $G$ be a structure group, and $P$ be a principal $G$-bundle on $X'$, classified by the map $f: X \to BG$.  The bundle $P$ can be assembled from its restrictions to $X$ and $e^i$, together with descent data; there is a pushout square

$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
\partial e^i \times G @>>> e^i \times G \\
@VV{\tilde{\phi}}V @VVV\\
P|_X @>>> P.
\end{CD}
$$

The map $\tilde{\phi}$ is a bundle map over $\phi$, and is in principle determined by the classifying map $f$.

> What is the attaching map $\tilde{\phi}$ in terms of $f$?

In other words, what's the map $$\tilde{\phi}: G \times \partial e^i \cong EG \times_{BG} \partial e^i \xrightarrow{1 \times \phi} EG \times_{BG} X = P|_X?$$

From this perspective, we see that choices of isomorphisms are involved.

If it helps, restrict to the case where $X$ is contractible.  Then $P|_X \cong X \times G$, and $\tilde{\phi}$ is determined by a map $$\partial e^i \times G \to G.$$  If the *homotopy class* of $f$ is known, can we write down an equation for the homotopy class of this map?

Here is [a related question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/178920/clutching-functions-and-classifying-maps).

Comment: I don't think $\bar\phi$ is going to have a nice description in terms of $f$. For example it exists given $P$ without assuming a particular classifying map is chosen for it. Moreover, it depends more on a particular choice of null-homotopy for $f|_{e^i}$ rather than the map $f$ itself, and this equivalent here to a choice of trivialisation $P|_{e^i}\cong e^i\times G$,

Comment: @Tyrone Yes, I was worried that this might be the case.  So if there's an answer, the phrase "in terms of $f$" must be interpreted very liberally.  Since there are choices of isomorphisms involved, I was hoping that the ambiguity can be packaged in the "homotopy class" of the transition function, but this might not be correct.